# An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable in a form

Tags: angularjs

I tried many answers here at Stackoverflow, but none of them working:

```
<form ng-submit="runIt(cars)">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="cars.erp" value="Toyota" ng-required="!cars.erp">Toyota
    <br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="cars.erp" value="Nissan" ng-required="!cars.erp">Nissan
    <br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="cars.erp" value="Honda" ng-required="!cars.erp">Honda
    <br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="cars.erp" value="Other" ng-required="!cars.erp">Other
    <input type="text" ng-model="cars.other" ng-show="cars.erp=='Other'" ng-required="!cars.other">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It all starts working only after typing a value in `Other`.  Apparently, this is due to hidden input, but this is how it should work:

- A value must be submitted,
- If Other selected, value must be typed.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/17426/

To reproduce:

- Run
- Select Toyota
- Click Submit
- See Console in Inspect

Comment: What browser were you using? It seems to work fine for me in Chrome

Comment: Chrome @riqitang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the specific error you're getting of "invalid form control with name='' is not focusable" is because the browser wants to focus on the form element that is required(the text input), but the element is not visible.

`<input type="text" ng-model="cars.other" ng-show="cars.erp=='Other'" ng-required="!cars.other">`

You're saying that the text field is only required if cars.other evaluates to false. In other words, you're saying that the text field is required whenever it isn't filled out. What you actually want is for the text field to be required if cars.erp is set to other.

`<input type="text" ng-model="cars.other" ng-show="cars.erp=='Other'" ng-required="cars.erp=='Other'">`

Answer (score 1):

Your text field's `ng-model` is `cars.other` and then you are checking for `ng-required="!cars.other"` which isn't right. You are requiring the text field with it self. Instead it should be dependent on the value of the radio button. Something like `ng-required="cars.erp=='Other'"`.

I have updated the JSFiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/d0o29hb2/3/. Hope this helps.